# jQuery-File-Upload blueimp configure

Tags: jquery

I'm going crazy to use this file upload. 
I want to upload a file with the ability to upload up to 4 photos. 
once loaded I should return the name of the photo. 
how do I set it up?
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set it up by including all required files and by running the following code:

`$('#INPUT_ID').fileupload('option', {
   url: 'URL_HERE',
   maxFileSize: 5000000,
   acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
});`

There are [more options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) and methods for more functionality